# How to migrate a Hyper-V VM from a Desktop PC to a Hyper-V cluster?

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, hyper-v

Migrating a VM with VMware is easy, from a Workstation to vSphere cluster it can be done with a VMware Converter.

I have little experience with Hyper-V though. There is a VM on a Hyper-V on Windows 8.1 and I have to move it to a Hyper-V Cluster.

How can I do it? Is there a tool like `Hyper-V Converter` or should I just move the VHD and recreate the VM on the Hyper-V cluster?

Comment: Does Hyper-V in Windows 8.1 support exporting a VM? If so then export it, copy it to the Hyper-V host, and import it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are excellent V2V Converters like ones StarWind and 5nine do but in your case you only need to a) export and b) import VM. See link below.

[Overview of exporting and importing a virtual machine (TechNet)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831535.aspx)

Comment: Just want to confirm that StarWind V2V Converter should work in this scenario. Here is the link just in case https://www.starwindsoftware.com/converter

Comment: Yeah, I actually did it with StarWind and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Export the VM.  Import it on the new machine.  You'll probably have to specify a few things like the network switch when you import.

Comment: Thanks buddy, it turned out that with hyper-v that's even easyer